# How to export Blender model with animation and materials?

Tags: animation, materials, export, alembic

I have created a very basic model of a horror creature that I want to export and use in another Blender scene. The creature consists of two separate meshes and two crudely animated armatures. The creatures are parented together with an empty. Whenever I export it as alembic I do have the animations baked but it doesn't have the material. Can someone please hint on the best way to do it?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alembic doesn't support materials. It can export the material slots assignations, but not the materials themselves.

But if you only want to use your model into another scene, you don't need to export it at all! Blender can "link" and "append" any data from any .blend file.

Before that, I highly recommend putting your asset in a collection with a clear identifiable name.

Just got to the menu File → Link/Append, navigate to the .blend file, then go to its Collection folder and select the collection of your asset.

The only difference between append and link it that <kbd>append</kbd> makes a full copy of your asset, while <kbd>link</kbd> only makes an instance out of the external file, allowing you to modify that source file and have the update in any Blender file it is linked into.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply. I have done as you suggested and it works, so I can carry on with my project.